# How do I pass a parameter to API request 2, which I receive from API response 1 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, axios, mobx

My 2 API calls happen to be at the same time, where the response of API1 is to be sent as a request parameter to API2. But, the value goes as undefined because it isn't fetched till that time. Is there any way this can be solved in react.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, I will explain one of the latest as well most sought after ways of solving the problem.

I am sure you would have heard of async/await in JavaScript, if you haven't I would suggest you to go through an MDN document around the topic.

There are 2 keywords here, **async** && **await**, let's see each of them one by one.

***Async***

Adding async before any function means one simple thing, instead of returning normal values, now the function will return a **Promise**

For example,

```
async function fetchData() {
 return ('some data from fetch call')
}
```

If you run the above function in your console simply by **fetchData()**. You'd see that instead of returning the string value, this function interestingly returns a **Promise**.

So in a nutshell async ensures that the function returns a promise, and wraps non-promises in it.

***Await***

I am sure by now, you would have guessed why we use keyword await in addition to ***async***, simply because the keyword ***await*** makes JavaScript wait until that promise (returned by the async function) settles and returns its result.

Now coming on to how could you use this to solve your issue, follow the below code snippet.

```
async function getUserData(){
 //make first request
 let response = await fetch('/api/user.json');
 let user     = await response.json();

 //using data from first request make second request/call
 let gitResponse = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`)
 let githubUser = await gitResponse.json()

 // show the avatar
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
  img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
  document.body.append(img);

 // wait 3 seconds
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));

  img.remove();

  return githubUser;
}
```

As you can see the above code is quite easy to read and understand. Also refer to [THIS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) document for more information on async/await keyword in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Asyn/await solves your problem:

```js
const requests = async () =>{
  const response1 = await fetch("api1")
  const result1 = await response1.json()

// Now you have result from api1 you might use it for body of api2 for exmaple
  const response2 = await fetch("api2", {method: "POST", body: result1})
  const result2 = await response1.json()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **react hooks**, you can use a **Promise** to chain your API calls in `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetchAPI1().then(fetchAPI2)
}, [])
```

[relevant Dan Abramov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326)

Comment: is there a way I can use reaction/wait from mobx?

Comment: there is probably a way you can use reaction/wait from mobx, though I can't say too much without knowing what you are going to do with those functions

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch(api1_url).then(response => {
 fetch(api2_url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: response
  })
  .then(response2 => {
    console.log(response2)
   })
 })
})
.catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error)
 });
```

> or if using axios

```
axios.post(api1_url, {
    paramName: 'paramValue'
})
  .then(response1 => {
     axios.post(api12_url, {
            paramName: response1.value
       })
  .then(response2 => {
     console.log(response2)
    })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Usage of this kind can lead to unnecessary bugs, as you are not checking for the result status fo the first request. What if the first request sent a 404 response or any other 4XX or 5XX response. We should always have a check for response status, before using that response value for a different network request.

Comment: Edited and added the correct approach to the above solution.